# Flash - AS3 - TextInput - Slow

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am using Adobe Flash CS6 to create a form that the user fills out.  There are 3 text input fields an a submit button. For the text input I am using the TextInput component (fl.controls.TextInput).  When the flash first loads the background, labels, and button display and about a second later the 3 text input fields show up.  Also when typing into the text fields there is a delay where I can type in something like "92683" and it seems to wait till I am done typing before the characters appear all at once.  Any ideas on what could be causing these problems?

I have 2 layers. 1 layer has the button, textinput and labels.  The other layer is the background that rotates between 3 background images every 10 seconds.

Comment: To resolve flash performance issues, it's best to isolate parts to see what's causing the performance issue. In other words, take your three text fields, put them into an otherwise empty .fla and see how it perform.  if it performs well, add the other parts of your application one piece at a time and test the performance again. Repeat until you get to the part that, when added, degrades the performance. Unfortunately since Flash is a mix of GUI and code, it's hard for SO members to help you troubleshoot your issue if no code is involved. And if no code is involved, this is off-topic for SO.

Comment: @user659616 What's your background weight?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use compressed bitmap images as background (don't use vectors).
You can compress here:  **File -> Publish Settings -> JPEG Quality**.

If you are creating this in air for mobile phones then, 
be sure you set render mode to **GPU**  (Application Settings -> General -> Render Mode : GPU)

Hope this helps!